# designate network id when creating the network

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Is there a way to specify a network id to the network and sub network during creation?

```
neutron net-create test-net --provider:network_type vlan --provider:physical_network physnet2 --provider:segmentation_id 22  
neutron subnet-create test-net --name test-subnet --allocation-pool start=10.153.9.20,end=10.153.9.34 --gateway 10.153.8.1 10.153.8.0/22
```

Comment: To what IP are you referring to?

Comment: @Athafoud sorry, i meant network id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as simple as NO! This option is not available from the command line client. For the supported parameters you can refer to:

- [netron net-create](http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/neutronclient_commands.html#neutronclient_subcommand_net-create)
- [neutron subnet-create](http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/neutronclient_commands.html#neutronclient_subcommand_subnet-create)

As I see it there is not a hint that this is going to be changed in the feature release.

If for any reason you still need to ad-hoc specify the Network ID, it is possible (I do not know how exactly) to do it manually by changing the values post-creation. But I discourage these action.